# How to run a ballerina service in background?

Tags: ballerina

ballerina run HelloService.bal will keep tailing the log in the terminal. 
Is there any way that we can run this in background ?

Comment: nohup ballerina run HelloService.bal will do the thing. But is this the recommended way ?

Comment: You will have to use nohup. I dont see any other solution to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As with any Unix process, just add & to the end of the command line. E.g.:

> ballerina run HelloService.bal &